# What happened to the Alien that came from the Space Jockey?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

In the derelict ship, the crew of the Nostromo find the Space Jockey.

[image: Space Jockey]

Apparently, he was infected by a Facehugger, so an Alien chest-buster had made his way out of his torso and bio suit.

What happened to this Alien?

Comment: What happened to the facehugger corpse for that matter?

Comment: Well, the FH corpse could be somewhere in the bowels of the ship. Just cuz he burst there doesn't mean he was implanted there.

Comment: True, there was some time between implantation and burstination.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is most likely the original Xenomorph that laid the eggs that filled the spaceship and attacks the crew of the Nostromo in Alien and provides the aliens for the colony which appears in Aliens.**

Of the alien itself, there is no mention, but it is reasonable to assume after laying eggs if it died, there was no reason for concern, the next generation of Xenomorphs was already underway. The eggs had shown remarkable environmental resistance and able to survive for millennia as they did in Aliens vs. Predator.

There is no reason to presume the Space Jockey was implanted on the ship, he may have been implanted at a previous location accounting for the lack of a facehugger corpse. It could have also been some time before he was discovered, it could have simply decayed.

Comment: When making the original *Alien*, there were no egg-laying Xenomorphs.  Ridley Scott's intention was that they took victims, cocooned them, and then those turned into eggs.  This is hinted at in the deleted scene were Ripley finds some of the missing crew, and they're cocooned into the wall.  The Queen was added as part of *Aliens*.

Comment: The act of cocooning human hosts turns the hosts into eggs? That IS a deleted scene I have to see. Are you sure?

Comment: Based on Wikipedia, most of the DVD releases of the film have the Director's Cut on them, which includes this scene.

Comment: @Thaddeus Gnovice's answer to this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12424/how-did-solitary-aliens-reproduce-in-the-alien-franchise contains the deleted scene you seek.

Comment: Well shut my mouth. This causes a problem. Where did the original eggs come from for Alien? This should imply there were other people on the Space Jockey's ship...

Comment: @Thaddeus It's theorized that the room filled with eggs was the cargo hold of the ship.  They were using the eggs as weapons.  Then, of course, things went wrong and one got loose.

Comment: Why weren't there canisters of Super-Goo Black instead of Xenomorph eggs? Isn't this guy supposed to be one of the 9 foot tall Humanoid aliens who was on his way to Earth to deliver a smackdown on the Human race?

Comment: @Thaddeus Nah, that's a (disappointing) retcon for _Prometheus_. There were no Engineers in the original _Alien_, just the Space Jockey. No black goo, either.